# Difference between Real time Kernel and RT Patch

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, real-time, yocto, patch

I want to apply the RT patch in my yocto build kernel So I searched over the internet and with results, I supposed that there are two things.

1. To make Real Time Kernel
2. To apply the RT patch in our existing kernel.

Is my assumption right? If yes, then kindly someone tell me what is difference between both. If No, then how can I apply RT Patch in my existing kernel or make my kernel real-time.

Any replies would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to think there are only 2?  Which set of RT patches are you looking at? Which Real Time Kernel are you looking at.  There are many.

Comment: Actually, I am not making for specific I am just getting knowledge for my project. I want to make my kernel real-time whether make it real-time or by applying the patch. And i want to know that is is possible to make my kernel real-time?

Comment: All kernels are realtime.  Specific patches reduce latency to solve specific problems.  Don't apply them unless you need them, as they hurt performance in other ways.

Comment: You must first design your real-time architecture and decide what exactly it is you need from the kernel. Can turn out that you don't need anything and the vanilla kernel is fine (if you use isolcpu, nohz_full and all that).